# Misunderstanding ArrowLoop when used with Netwire

Tags: haskell, frp, arrows, netwire

Following the lead of the excellent answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976944/how-does-arrowloop-work-also-mfix), I'm trying to get a working example of `ArrowLoop` that doesn't use arrow notation. I'm uncomfortable using arrow notation until I fully understand how arrows work under the hood. That being said, I've constructed a small program that based on my (limited) understanding of Arrows should work. However, it ends up terminating with the dreaded `<<loop>>` exception:

```
module Main where

import Control.Wire
import FRP.Netwire

farr :: SimpleWire (Int, Float) (String, Float)
farr = let
  fn :: Int -> Float -> ((String, Float), SimpleWire (Int, Float) (String, Float))
  fn i f = (("f+i: " ++ (show (fromIntegral i + f)), f + 0.1), loopFn)

  loopFn :: SimpleWire (Int, Float) (String, Float)
  loopFn = mkSFN $ \(i, f) -> fn i f
  in
   mkSFN $ \(i, _) -> fn i 0.0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let sess = clockSession_ :: Session IO (Timed NominalDiffTime ())
  (ts, sess2) <- stepSession sess

  let wire = loop farr
      (Right s, wire2) = runIdentity $ stepWire wire ts (Right 0)

  putStrLn ("s: " ++ s)

  (ts2, _) <- stepSession sess2
  let (Right s2, _) = runIdentity $ stepWire wire2 ts (Right 1)

  putStrLn ("s2: " ++ s2)
```

My intuition tells me that the `<<loop>>` exception usually comes when you don't supply the initial value to the loop. Haven't I done that with the line containing `fn i 0.0`? The output disagrees:

```
$ ./test
s: f+i: 0.0
test.exe: <<loop>>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: <<loop>> Is GHCs way of telling you that it has detected an evaluation loop; an expression where during GHCs evaluation it ran back into the same thunk.

Comment: Right, I'd like a little more explanation about why it's happening in this case, since I don't expect it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point of confusion seemed to be the integral relationship between `ArrowLoop` and `mfix`. For the uninitiated, `fix` is a function that [finds the fixed point](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion) of a given function:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

`mfix` is the monadic extension of this function, whose type signature is, unsurprisingly:

```
mfix :: (a -> m a) -> m a
```

So what does this have to do with `ArrowLoop`? Well, the `ArrowLoop` instance for Netwire runs `mfix` on the second argument of the passed wire. To put it another way, consider the type signature for `loop`:

```
loop :: a (b, d) (c, d) -> a b c
```

In Netwire, the instance of `ArrowLoop` is:

```
instance MonadFix m => ArrowLoop (Wire s e m)
```

This means that the `loop` function's type when used with wires is:

```
loop :: MonadFix m => Wire s e m (b, d) (c, d) -> Wire s e m b c
```

Since `loop` does not take an initial argument of type `d`, this means that there is no way to initialize any sort of conventional "looping" over the wire. The only way to get a value out of it is to keep applying the output as the input until it finds a termination condition, which is analogous to the way `fix` works. The wire that gets passed as an argument to `loop` never actually steps more than once, since `stepWire` is applied to the same wire over and over with different inputs. Only when the wire actually produces a fixed value, does the function step and produce another wire (which behaves the same way as the first).

For completeness, here is code for my original intuition for how `loop` was supposed to work, which I have named `semiLoop`:

```
semiLoop :: (Monad m, Monoid s, Monoid e) => c -> Wire s e m (a, c) (b, c) -> Wire s e m a b
semiLoop initialValue loopWire = let
  runLoop :: (Monad m, Monoid s, Monoid e) =>
             Wire s e m (a, c) (b, c) -> s -> a -> c -> m (Either e b, Wire s e m a b)
  runLoop wire ts ipt x = do
    (result, nextWire) <- stepWire wire ts (Right (ipt, x))
    case result of
      Left i -> return (Left i, mkEmpty)
      Right (value, nextX) ->
        return (Right value, mkGen $ \ts' ipt' -> runLoop nextWire ts' ipt' nextX)
  in
   mkGen $ \ts input -> runLoop loopWire ts input initialValue
```

### Edit

After the [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256138/convert-from-arrow-notation/25266149#25266149) provided by Petr, the `delay` combinator is essential to preventing the `loop` combinator from diverging. `delay` simply creates a single-value buffer between the laziness of using the next value in the `mfix` portion of the loop described above. An identical definition of `semiLoop` above is therefore:

```
semiLoop :: (MonadFix m, Monoid s, Monoid e) =>
            c -> Wire s e m (a, c) (b, c) -> Wire s e m a b
semiLoop initialValue loopWire = loop $ second (delay initialValue) >>> loopWire
```