# How does this definition of ArrowLoop.loop work?

Tags: haskell, arrows

The function instance for `ArrowLoop` contains

```
loop :: ((b,d) -> (c,d)) -> (b -> c)
loop f b = let (c,d) = f (b,d) in c
```

First I have a problem with the signature: How can we possibly get `b -> c` from `(b,d) -> (c,d)`? I mean, the `c` in the resulting tuple may depend on both elements of the input, how is it possible to "cut off" the influence of `d`?

Second I don't get how the `let` works here. Doesn't contain `(c,d) = f (b,d)` a cyclic definition for `d`? Where does `d` come from? To be honest, I'm surprised this is valid syntax, as it looks like we would kind of redefine `d`.

I mean in mathematics this would make kind of sense, e.g. f could be a complex function, but I would provide only the real part b, and I would need to chose the imaginary part d in a way that it doesn't change when I evaluate f (b,d), which would make it some kind of fixed point. But if this analogy holds, the `let` expression must somehow "search" for that fixed point for d (and there could be more than one). Which looks close to magic to me. Or do I think too complicated?

Comment: [How does the Haskell rec-keyword works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405850/how-does-the-haskell-rec-keyword-work/5406008#5406008) The first answer answers your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works the same way the standard definition of `fix` works:

```
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

i.e., it's finding a fixed point in the [exact same way `fix` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787421/how-do-i-use-fix-and-how-does-it-work): recursively.

For instance, as a trivial example, consider `loop (\((),xs) -> (xs, 1:xs)) ()`. This is just like `fix (\xs -> 1:xs)`; we ignore our input, and use the `d` output (here `xs`) as our main output. The extra element in the tuple that `loop` has is just to contain the input parameter and output value, since arrows can't do currying. Consider how you'd define a factorial function with `fix` — you'd end up using currying, but when using arrows you'd use the extra parameter and output that `loop` gives you.

Basically, `loop` ties a knot, giving a arrow access to an auxiliary output of itself, just like `fix` ties a knot, giving a function access to its own output as an input.

Answer (score 6):

"Search for the fixed point" is *exactly* what this does.  This is Haskell's laziness in action.  See more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fixed-point_combinator&useformat=desktop#Implementing_fixed-point_combinators).